# Passing values from webservice called by another application to asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asmx

Asp.net page is opening java web start application.This application is calling .asmx web service.I want to send parameter from this web service back to asp.net web page.

Answer (score 0):

To pass data to ASP.NET it works just like any other web application. You either send it back via HTTP GET or HTTP POST.

If you are doing a GET then you would do it via the query string such as:

https://www.mysite.com.au/foobar?u=homer&age=123

where the query string is the part after the ?. Doing it via POST is similair. I suggest you go and read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 which gives you code on how to do both.

Comment: There are multiple users with different login id and password.For every user the webservice returns different values.and there is no connection from asp.net page to web service.

Web Service has to find that particular user and send the value.

Comment: This is starting to sound like an architectural problem. Ultimately there has to be something "common" between the web service and the asp.net. Perhaps the storage layer (database), and you would then pass around a token between the web service and the asp.net so that you can "link them up".

Comment: I have been advised to use socket programming.
I'm not sure whether it will work or not.

Comment: @JessJoseph You can use sockets but then you have to manage all things about the connection etc. The only time sockets will be beneficial over REST using HTTP is if you don't want to drop the connection. In that case use WebSockets.